# Debenu PDF works on localhost fails on azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, pdf, azure-web-app-service

I'm using [Debenu PDF Library](http://www.debenu.com/) to extract pages from a pdf file. Here is how I do it,

```
var pdflib = new PDFLibrary(LoadDll());
int result = pdflib.UnlockKey("UNLOCKKEYISHERE");

AzureStorageWrapper sasWrapper = new AzureStorageWrapper(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureStorageConnection"], "cont1");
byte[] blob = sasWrapper.GetBlob("file.pdf");

pdflib.LoadFromString(blob, "");
byte[] page = pdflib.RenderPageToString(50, 1, 1);
```

When I run this on my local machine it works perfectly (first page of the PDF file comes to the `page` byte array).

But after publishing this as an Azure Web App `page` gets a some useless string of bytes.

Can anyone explain to me why this is?

Answer (score 2):

You've hit an Azure App Service sandbox runtime exectution limitation.

From https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks:

> Unsupported frameworks
>
> Here is a list of frameworks and scenarios that have been found to be not be usable due to one or more of the restrictions above. It's conceivable that some will be supported in the future as the sandbox evolves.
>
> PDF generators failing due to restriction mentioned above:
>
> EVOPDF
>   Rotativa
>   wkhtmltopdf
>   Syncfusion
>   Siberix
>   NReco (uses wkhtmltopdf)
>   Spire.PDF
>
> Other scenarios:
>   PhantomJS/Selenium: tries to connect to local address, and also uses GDI+.

It's probably safe to say you can add **Debenu PDF** to that list.

There is however a mention that some GDI calls **may** work on Basic/Standard pricing tiers in App Service. It's worth giving that a go if you're currently on Free/Shared.

Alternatives to App Service for running stuff that uses GDI/GDI+:

- A Web/Worker Role (Cloud Services)
- Service Fabric
- IaaS Virtual Machine

Similar question here:
[What could cause EvoPDF "unable to render html" exception when deployed to Azure Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558044/what-could-cause-evopdf-unable-to-render-html-exception-when-deployed-to-azure/38575067?noredirect=1#comment64539298_38575067)

Comment: EvoPdf has a solution for Azure Websites. Check the http://www.evopdf.com/azure-html-to-pdf-converter.aspx page for more details.

Comment: The Wiki is now updated to reflect that -- https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks

Comment: Thanks for updating that wiki page. May I suggest you to remove EvoPdf from that list of Azure incompatible frameworks and add it to a section containg the solutions addressing the Azure sandbox limitations? Currently there is a little bit of contradictory info our there. Is it possible for me to get edit permissions on that wiki page somehow? Thanks.

Comment: I think it's best you open an Issue here https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues - easier to track. Thanks!